# create a section plane for archviz

Tags: modifiers

I have a 3d model (a house - with doors /windows/ holes /floors). I want to see from ortho top view and want to make a section. I tried to use BIM or camera clipping , but the result not as i expected because the cutting area is hollow ( rather than solid - which i prefer).

check the blenderBIM in creating section plane :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPGFC566Lmc

Like in my screenshot, a simple example : the section is created from top but i can see the cylinder. I want the section to be like solid , so we shouldn't see the cylinder in the middle.

One perfect result , of course by using boolean, but i have a lot of house elements. I don't want to use this method. BIM addon is almost perfect, it's just i don't like that hollow.

Is there any other method ?

[image]

Comment: You might want to check the `bpy.ops.bisect` operator which is certainly used in the add-on. It has a `use_fill` parameter which fills the sections when needed. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/bisect.html?highlight=bisect . You can also use it as a tool if you click and keep the mouse pressed for about a second on the knife tool in edit mode

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex problem for architectural models and Blender's out of the box tools just don't quite cut it (pardon the pun), unfortunately. The closest I believe we're getting to it is true architectural cutting which is a work in progress here: https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell/issues/1153

Unfortunately, it is not yet ready.